# What headers or javascript do I add to the HTML to reject older browsers?

Tags: javascript, browser, compatibility

Developing a frontend realtime javascript application, we have decided to drop support for older browsers since it takes too much effort to support them.

What header or javascript should we add in the HTML, so that when they hit the URL, I can redirect them a page to obtain newer browsers before proceeding to our application?

Comment: Which older browsers? You have to be more specific.

Comment: You should do this with serverside code in case the older browsers don't support JavaScript.

Comment: @Blender, you mean I should read the HTTP request header on the server to do this?

Comment: @jeff, but it does not have to be specific. In general, what would be the approach to do it, as in the future, there will be newer browsers also.

Comment: You can use feature detection to detect older browsers.

Comment: @nhahtdh, thanks. I know there are library for feature detection. It will be better for us to make it simple for the client to install newer versions of browser.

Comment: @hllau - There is no general way to detect old browsers, though. If you want to do that, you should be using feature detection (as already suggested to you).

Comment: You don't need a library for feature detection.

Comment: @nnnnnn, may I know what you use for detecting feature then?

Comment: Depends on the feature, but jeff's answer gave an example. (Again depending on the feature that's what libraries do internally.)

Answer (score 2):

you can use following properties of navigator object

```
 navigator.appCodeName 
 navigator.appName 
 navigator.appVersion
 navigator.cookieEnabled 
navigator.platform 
 navigator.userAgent
```

you can also use jquery browser object
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

Answer (score 1):

The better option is to use feature detection. For example, to test if a browser has geolocation support, you can use the following:

```
if (navigator.geolocation)
{
    // interact with geolocation features
}
```

---

If you insist on using browser detection instead, however, you can use the following to detect if the browser is using IE 8 or below:

```
function getInternetExplorerVersion()
// Returns the version of Windows Internet Explorer or a -1
// (indicating the use of another browser).
{
   var rv = -1; // Return value assumes failure.
   if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
   {
      var ua = navigator.userAgent;
      var re  = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
      if (re.exec(ua) != null)
         rv = parseFloat( RegExp.$1 );
   }
   return rv;
}

var ver = getInternetExplorerVersion(); // example: 8.0
var belowIE8 = ver <= 8.0;
```

Found here: http://www.mkyong.com/javascript/how-to-detect-ie-version-using-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to determine this based on a particular JavaScript version, see below code (untested):

```
<script language="javascript1.5">
var supported = true;
</script>
<script>
if ('undefined' === typeof supported) {
    alert('not at least 1.5 supported');
}
```

It's still better to do feature detection though, as that ties in better with what you're going to use it for.

Comment: This is a nice way. I also know there are library for feature detection in javascript. How do I know the Javascript version running on different browsers?

Comment: @hllau in this way, you can only detect from version X upwards, not exact versions; but you can just create a slew of them together: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/languageattri3.shtml